# Firefox Add-on, how to track the origin of a new tab?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am building a Firefox addon using the addon-SDK. I need to track new tabs and find out if there were opened from a link in another tab using the 'Open link in new tab' option. Tracking new tabs is fairly easy from the main script:

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

tabs.on('open', function(tab){

  tab.on('ready', function(tab){
  //do stuff with the new tab
  }

}
```

But I can not figure out if there is any way of finding out the origin of say tab. I had thought of inserting a script into all tabs that listens for the context menu event or something similar, but that feels more like a hack than a solution. Am I missing something obvious in mi ignorance?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the current active tab to be the origin of any new tab in most cases:

```
tabs.on('open', function(tab) {
  var origin = tabs.activeTab;
  // do something 
}
```

I'm not sure if this covers all cases. You probably need to test a few things things like links that open and activate new tabs or tabs that are opened asynchronously (which is blocked by default though).

Comment: This was another solution I considered, but tabs opened with Ctrl + T trigger the same event and are saved with the wrong origin with this method. Ctrl + T tabs should have no origin.

Answer (score 0):

Though I haven't tested it, you could try to create a listener on the context menu like so:

```
const doc = require('sdk/window/utils').getMostRecentBrowserWindow().document;
var openInTab = doc.getElementById('context-openlinkintab');
openInTab.addEventListener('click', callback);
```

This assumes that the default event listener allows bubbling, assumes that the element is hidden and shown between uses rather than destroyed and re-created, and probably isn't fired when a user cmd/ctrl clicks a link, but it's a step in what I think will be a hacky solution.

The name of the function that fires when that element is clicked is called `gContextMenu.openLinkInTab()`. If you can get your function to fire whenever that function runs, you're golden. Not too sure how, though.

Answer (score 0):

both methods recommended by users above willma and kapep are flawed

your first step is to identify all methods that can open new tab (maybe new window)

here are the different situations for when a new tab is opened:

1. user middle clicks search icon from search bar or middle clicks go icon from url bar
2. user presses alt+enter from search bar or url bar
3. user has addon installed where if you ight click in search bar or url bar then middle click and pick "paste & search" it will open in new tab
4. user presses tab key to get to a link and then presses ctrl+enter to open it in new tab
5. user right clicks link and clicks open in new tab
6. user has [TabSubmit](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tabsubmit/?src=search) addon and middle clicks on button to open in new tab (possible ctrl+enter on button to open in new tab)
7. 3rd party application opens link in firefox (new tab or new window)

if user right clicks a link and says open in new window will you make parent of that window the tab? i know for sure there is a fiefox xpcom function that holds the opener window, so you can find parent window.

add other methods to open new windows/tabs in this list then we will look for a commonality between them all. im thinking referer on http-channel-modify-request and last active tab (as recommended by kapep).

i might be over-thinking this, im not sure.

Comment: My main concern is with tracking when a user opens a new tab as a result of clicking a link, situations 4 or 5 in your list mainly. Anything else I can ignore for now. I am going to do some research on xpcom function you commented to see if I can come up with something

Comment: it would be an incomplete addon bro you'll get complaints, personally i would list them all and find a solution that fits all, rather than code for just 4 and 5 and then revisit and code for others, beginnings of sloppy (and likely hacky and maybe even buggy) code. but totally up to you.

Comment: Noted. I will go trough your list and try to find some sort or trigger that works for all cases

Comment: cool move man. let me know if you come up with any other situations to add to the list ill edit it in. its an interesting subject to me.